Teamcity agent requirements ARM64?
Is there a more standard way to make sure that the Teamcity build agent is an ARM64 machine?
Right now I am using the jvm.os.arch explicit requirements but that seems more like a hack, is another variable/build requirement I can use?
# Explicit Requirements
teamcity.agent.jvm.os.arch  equals aarch64


AFAIK this parameter refers to the JVM that runs the agent itself, so I wouldn't call it a hack. It's one of the predefined build parameters so it looks like the most stable thing to rely on.
You can also define some custom properties on your agent but it will likely be too much maintenance efforts (and errors, if the configuration is not automated).
